# Python Graphic Game Assistance

Tags: python, graphics, sentinel

The entire program can be summed up in a few sentences. A graphic game based off two players choosing to either roll a die (1-6) or pass their turn (total of 3 passes available per player). Whoever's total rolls add up to 21 first loses, and the other wins.

I am having difficulty launching into the sentinel loop that allows player 1 and player 2 to begin the game. The function I am using to detect whether or not the player(s) have selected one of the two graphic "buttons" is as follows:

```
def inbetween(pt1, pt2, pt3):
    return (pt1.getX()<=pt2.getX()<=pt3.getX()) and (pt1.getY()<=pt2.getY()<=pt3.getY())
```

This function works fine as I have used it for other similar programs, my main issue is with being able check if the users click is within TWO different buttons (i.e. calling inbetween function twice). This would then be the prompt for entering the sentinel loop.

Any and all help is appreciated, thank you for your time. I had examples of the program as photos but stackoverflow marked it as spam.

Comment: `if inbetween(...) or inbetween(...):` will tell if they're within one or the other. But don't you have a way to attach a function to run whenever a button is clicked? Most grame frameworks handle this for you.

Comment: Well for this "game" I am going through the graphics package for Python. So the strategy I have been introduced to so far is to get the click positioning within the window and then utilize the inbetween() function to see whether or not it is within either of the buttons.

Comment: Consider using `pygame` instead of low-level graphics.